# ng-repeat of directives, only last element responds to resize event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very simple directive that is supposed to change its width in response to the `$window.onresize` event. For some reason only the last element/directive in the `ng-repeat` array responds and changes its css accordingly.

```
<!-- html -->
<tile class="tile" ng-repeat="tile in tiles"></tile>
```

```
// js
function main ($scope) {
  $scope.tiles = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    $scope.tiles.push({ active: false })
  }
}

function tile ($window) {
  return {
    link: (scope, el, attr) => {
      let $main = document.querySelector('.right')      

      el.css({
        display: `inline-block`,
        padding: `1rem`,
        border: `1px solid #ccc`,
        width: `${$main.clientWidth / 3}px`
      })

      $window.onresize = () => {
        console.log($main.clientWidth)
        scope.$apply(() => {
          el.css({
            width: `${$main.clientWidth / 3}px`
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('main', main)
  .directive('tile', tile)
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/LNxBmo?editors=1010)

Comment: ...Is there a reason that you don't just use flexbox instead?

Comment: Yes this the first step of a much more complicated series of animations.

Comment: As `window.onresize` has a single copy for all the `tile` directives rendered using `ng-repeat` and hence it gets overrided for each element of `tile` directive which results into execution of  `window.onresize` overrided or assigned by last element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning your handler to `$window.onresize`, thus overwriting all previous handlers.

Try doing the following instead:

```
// instead of $window.onresize = ...
angular.element($window).bind('resize', () => ...)
```

This way you're binding to the `resize` event instead of assigning a single handler to it.

Comment: Gorgeous. Makes perfect sense.